# Excel: Sort by result of comparison

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I think it'll be easier to elaborate by explaining with the rules and example.

In a soccer competition (UEFA Euro), there are several groups of four teams each. Top two teams from each group qualify to the next stage. If two teams have the same number of points, say Team A and Team B, then the higher standing will be given to the team that won the match between the two. So if Team B beat Team A, they will qualify even if they have scored less goals in total.

I have the group structure laid out, as well as the fixtures. I have each two team's individual final result in separate cells next to their names. Example:

```
Cell AA4: Team A name
Cell AB4: Team A score 
Cell AE4: Team B name
Cell AD4: Team B score
```

Standings table:

```
Team name: D column
Num of points: L column
```

I know how to set the primary sorting column to be the total amount of points, but how can I tell Excel to then check (if necessary) the result between the two teams ***if*** they have the same amount of points, by looking at **the match result between them**? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's a little tricky indeed. You should use the secondary level of sorting in Excel and create an extra column at the same level of the number of points per team you use for your primary filter.

In this second column you have to compute delta score by making a subtraction of the score of teams that have the same number of points.

1- Reorder your data so you can use vlookup :

```
Cell A4: Team A name
Cell B4: Team A score 
Cell A5: Team B name
Cell B5: Team B score
```

2- In the new delta score column, check if two team have the same number of points, and if yes, compute difference between the two teams:

```
=IF(F4=F5,VLOOKUP(E4,$A$4:$B$5,2,FALSE)-VLOOKUP(E5,$A$4:$B$5,2,FALSE),0)
```

With :

```
Cell E4 : Team A Name
Cell F4 : Team A points
Cell E5 : Team B Name
Cell F5 : Team B points
...
```

3- Sort with 2 levels : first on points column, second on delta score column. Sort from greater to lower on both cases.

If team A and team B have the same number of points, second column will be used. Second raw will always be zero (because compared to third raw). On the first raw though, if A bet B, delta will be positive, it will rank before zero so first, otherwise, it will be negative and rank second.

It should work. Let me know if you have questions :)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding this. Perhaps it's just me. I've added the correct cell ordering and the layout of my standings as well in the question. Are you sure this will work?

Comment: Note that teams will play with more than one team.

Comment: The trick is to manage to create a secondary column that gives a clue on the result of the game and use it as a secondary sorting key. My solution doesn't take in account the whole complexity of all the games but explains the principles of retrieving the game result and using it as the secondary sorting key. It is easier to explain with an excel file...

Comment: @Tomaka I don't see the point of your answer if it doesn't take the whole complexity of all group matches into consideration. All you're doing is explaining the problem again, which we all understood in the first place.